# automating clicking open on " is an application downloaded from the internet" using ant

Tags: macos, testing, ant, automation, installation

I am automating an application install on mac os 10.7 to 10.10 using ant and would like to automate clicking the open button on the "xyz is an application downloaded from the internet...." box, preferably using the gui in a testable way. I've looked at applescript but the editor doesn't seem to recognise that button click. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it need to be via the GUI? You can just use `xattr -c` _app_ to remove the quarantine attribute (which is triggering the downloaded from the internet warning dialog).

Comment: It would have been preferable but it looks it looks like we're going to have to go about it your way, GUI seems to be too much work for too little reward. Thanks!